# как добавить субдомен для localhost?

Tags: .htaccess, apache, localhost, lamp

На локальном компьютере установлен LAMP.

Cайт на localhost работает по принципу единой точки входа, .htaccess имеет следующий вид:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

В `C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` к уже существующей строке `127.0.0.1 localhost` добавлена строка `127.0.0.1 test.localhost` , но сайт не "подхватывается", `test.localhost` в адресной строке отправляется в гугл в качестве поискового запроса.

Вопрос:

что следует сделать, чтобы localhost "подхватывал" добавляемые субдомены, например, **test**.localhost, или где об этом можно почитать?

**UPD**:

Проблема "невидимости поддомена" наблюдается только в Google Chrome(58, последний). В Firefox(53) и в IE(11) такого поведения нет. Chrome перезагружал с очисткой кеша и аппаратной перезагрузкой (и просто закрытием/запуском), но проблема не исчезла.

Comment: А чем использование другого порта не устраивает?

Comment: Если по test.localhost открывается гугл, значит это проблемы вашего браузера, а вы его не назвали

Comment: @AGS17 некрасиво, лично я для себя тоже субдоменов к localhost посоздавал)

Comment: @andreymal так если некрасиво, почему нельзя взять красивый? Почему именно субдомен локалхоста?

Comment: @AGS17 потому что он остаётся локалхостом и за пределами компьютерами не используется, зачем другими названиями в заблуждение вводить)

Comment: @andreymal, и правда, такая проблема наблюдается только в Google Chrome(58, последний). В Firefox(53) и в IE(11) такого поведения нет. Chrome я перезагружал с очисткой кеша и аппаратной перезагрузкой (и просто закрытием/запуском), но проблема не исчезла. В чем может быть причина?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решением вопроса стало добавление префикса "**http://**", после чего  Chrome начал нормально обрабатывать адрес http://test.localhost